# Подстановка данных в переменную из другой переменной

Tags: golang

```
reportFill := "за период с %s"
time := time.Now().Format("02.01.2006")
```

Помогите объединить эти 2 строки в одну с подстановкой данных из переменной `time`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать как угодно

в одну строку:

```
attr := fmt.Sprintf("за период с %s", time.Now().Format("02.01.2006"))
```

в две:

```
reportFill := "за период с %s"
attr := fmt.Sprintf(reportFill , time.Now().Format("02.01.2006"))
```

https://play.golang.org/p/HFZc47m8U30

**UPD:**

Изначальный код больше похож на возможность гибкой установки формата вывода. В таком случае упрощать код нужно не избавлением от промежуточных переменных, а выносом установки этих переменных во внешние функции.

Например если вы хотите менять язык вывода:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

const (
    ENG = iota
    RUS
)

var reportFill = "since %s" // значение по умолчанию, если язык не задан

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

const (
    ENG = iota
    RUS
)

var reportFill = "since %s" // значение по умолчанию, если язык не задан

func main() {

    // устанавливаем язык на русский и проверяем вывод
    setLang(RUS)
    attr := fmt.Sprintf(reportFill, time.Now().Format("02.01.2006"))
    fmt.Println(attr)

    // устанавливаем язык на английский и проверяем вывод
    setLang(ENG)
    attr = fmt.Sprintf(reportFill, time.Now().Format("02.01.2006"))
    fmt.Println(attr)
}

// установка переменных форматирования строк в зависимости от выбранного языка
func setLang(lang int) {
    switch lang {
    case ENG:
        reportFill = "since %s"
    case RUS:
        reportFill = "за период с %s"
    }
}
```

Видно, что получение значения для `attr` в основном коде происходит опять же в одну строку (что удобно). Но при этом вы сохраняете возможность изменить формат и даже используете это в некой логике (функция `setLang`).

https://play.golang.org/p/4TbZ4vD4g4j

Comment: Да я так и сделал, дело в том, что я потом передаю его в excel а он вносит его вот так today%!(EXTRA string=15.02.2021), притом в консоль выводится нормально за период с 15.02.2021

Comment: видимо что-то все таки не так, в playground же такой вывод как вам нужен?

Comment: когда отправляю в excel обернул в string(attr) все хорошо, спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 2):

используйте [fmt.Sprintf](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/)

```
reportFill := "за период с %s"
time := time.Now().Format("02.01.2006")

println(fmt.Sprintf(reportFill, time))
```

Comment: attr := fmt.Sprintf(reportFill, time.Now().Format("02.01.2006")) завожу в переменную и на выходе получаю вот такой ответ, today%!(EXTRA string=15.02.2021) данные вставляю в excel